# Tool to create ASCII graph from a set of vertices and edges?

Tags: graph, ascii

Is there a tool that takes as input a series of vertices and edges, and outputs a graph in ASCII/Unicode format?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes!  Perl has [`Graph::Easy`](http://bloodgate.com/perl/graph/manual/), as described in [this Hacker News comment](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2652047).

Here's some output from the [online demo](http://bloodgate.com/graph-demo):

```
........     +---------+     +-----+
: Bonn : --> | Berlin  | ..> | Ulm |
:......:     +---------+     +-----+
               H
               H train
               v
             +---------+
             | Koblenz |
             +---------+
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [Graph::Easy](http://bloodgate.com/perl/graph/manual/) mentioned by @nibot, there are a couple of other tools around for this:

- Vijual (Clojure): http://lisperati.com/vijual/
- ascii-graphs (Scala): https://github.com/mdr/ascii-graphs

(Disclaimer: I'm the developer of the latter).

Comment: Who downvoted this? References to other libraries is a perfectly fine answer to me.

Answer (score 5):

For whoever reading this post in 2022, check out [Diagon](https://github.com/ArthurSonzogni/Diagon).
There are both a command line tool `diagon` and a [website](https://arthursonzogni.com/Diagon).

you can create multiple ASCII visualization from text such as :

- DAG
- flowchart
- sequence diagram
- mathematical expression (without Latex)

DAG Example :

```
┌─────┐┌─────────┐┌─────┐     
│socks││underwear││shirt│     
└┬────┘└┬─┬──────┘└┬─┬──┘     
 │      │┌▽─────┐  │┌▽───────┐
 │      ││pants │  ││tie     │
 │      │└┬──┬──┘  │└┬───────┘
┌▽──────▽─▽┐┌▽─────▽┐│        
│shoes     ││belt   ││        
└──────────┘└┬──────┘│        
┌────────────▽───────▽┐       
│jacket               │       
└─────────────────────┘
```

Also worth looking : https://www.plantuml.com/

Answer (score 1):

I might recommend [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) -- I don't know if it has an ascii-art output, but it does support a heap of other useful formats, and perhaps you can find a converter to ascii art from one of those formats.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ascii-seq

input.txt

```
From -- message -> To .. response -> From
-- line --
Another -- msg -> Dest
Self -- abc -> Self
```

`npx ascii-seq input.txt` or `cat input.txt | npx ascii-seq`

```
┌──────┐        ┌────┐┌─────────┐┌──────┐┌──────┐  
│ From │        │ To ││ Another ││ Dest ││ Self │  
└───┬──┘        └──┬─┘└────┬────┘└───┬──┘└───┬──┘  
    │              │       │         │       │     
    ├── message ──>│       │         │       │     
    │              │       │         │       │     
    │<∙ response ∙∙┤       │         │       │     
    │              │       │         │       │     
    │              │       │         │       │     
────────────────────── line ───────────────────────
    │              │       │         │       │     
    │              │       │         │       │     
    │              │       ├─ msg ──>│       │     
    │              │       │         │       │     
    │              │       │         │       ├──┐  
    │              │       │         │       │  abc
    │              │       │         │       │<─┘  
    │              │       │         │       │     
    │              │       │         │       │     
    │              │       │         │       │
```

Answer (score -6):

yes, Its called unix directories and the 'tree' cmd.

Output example:

```
db
├── colors
│   ├── green
│   └── nongreen
└── person
    └── type
        ├── alien
        │   └── colors -> db/colors
        ├── female
        │   └── colors -> db/colors
        └── male
            └── colors -> db/colors
```

Comment: how does one compute these edges? green and non green have an edge from person in their row.